# Automatic shapefile input for pre-constructed QGIS workflows?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-2, qgis-processing

I currently have two models running:

1. Take shapefiles and break them down into separate shapefiles based on their class, and save them in a specific folder;
2. Select the broken-down shapefiles with the classes I want and merge them. Then, after they are merged, dissolve and save as a new shapefile.

These models work fine but the problem is that I have a lot of files to run these processes on. Each run takes roughly an hour and I'd like to just leave the computer running for a day so I dont have to keep checking back on the progress.

Is there a way such that QGIS can automatically input those files into the model and iterate through, other than just adding more arguments and parameters to my existing model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I would do several  `extract by attributes`

and then merge the extracted together. This can be done in one and the same moddel.

[image]

But to be sure, you have to be more specific about what algorithms you are using to break them down.

Comment: Thanks for your tip about extract by attributes - This will save lots of time! I was using split vector layer to deconstruct the shapefile and then putting the selected classes back together with a different model. However, the other part of my question relates to the automation of the algorithm (which will look very similar to the one you provided here). I was wondering if there's anyway for me to make the algorithm source the shapefiles automatically, so I can run large number of files without me re-entering the parameters every time I finish processing a file?